# Can't figure out why bootstrap navbar collapse toggle isn't working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I copy and pasted the bootstrap navbar into codepen but I can't get any of the dropdown navbars to work. I'm trying to make a webpage where when viewed in mobile, you can use the dropdown button to navigate but I'm not having any luck. Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/michaelaharvey/pen/xZKgOX?editors=100
Thank you!!!

```
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: Did you include jquery in your code? Navbar collapse require jquery to work.

Comment: Thanks!!! that worked!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you're not including bootstrap.js in the Codepen. Your code works fine..

http://www.codeply.com/go/uZa8lR5x9w

Answer (score 0):

In codepen settings add another resource under jquery,then paste this : `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js`